# Display a custom Babylon JS scene as the Babylon viewer does?

Tags: babylonjs

I have a Babylon JS based program that creates (from simple objects (cubes)) and displays that scene.
I can also save that scene as a GLB file.
There is also a Babylon JS Viewer which is able to display that GLB file.

Is there a way to display the created scene as the viewer does (ie create the same space cube, lights and camera)?

Answer (score -1):

If you export your scene as a GLB file if you want to reimport it you have to use BABYLON Gltf loader 
https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/load_from_any_file_type

The scene will be loaded by default to the (0, 0, 0) position.

For further info and discuss with the community you can directly go to https://forum.babylonjs.com/

Comment: I know how to export and import the GLB file. That is how I know how it looks. My questions was, if there is a simple way to achieve the same effect (ie how to automatically place the camera, lights and skybox like the viewer does).